# "Error Loading Page" in CodeIgniter-PHP

Tags: php, mysql, css, codeigniter

[error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqsOy.png)I'm trying to update an app that we've been using for the last year - somebody else wrote it.  It's been in production, on Godaddy, MySQL 5.5.46, and working fine.  I dumped to my local machine in a XAMPP (5.6.3-0) development environment, which has (I think) MySQL 5.0.11...

We were using CodeIgniter 2.2.x, and I started with that.  I've got it set on 'localhost/rides/', so there's one additional url segment,

The problem is this:  The initial view loads fine.  After that, I can't get any views to load - I just get a "Error Loading Page" error.  It doesn't stop anything, the message is css formatted to match the site (see the image)...  I've tried calling views from other controllers, calling different views, forcing the uri and url, and tested every combination of directory segments.  Occasionally I get the 403 error message, which I assume is a path error (related to security).  I've spent about a day working on this, and have figured out that the controllers all load fine, the models load, the database is initialized - I just can't get the views to load after the original index.php.  I've also worked from the config.php side, fixing the paths, and I've tried all of the path resolution options offered by CI.  I've also upgraded to CI 3.

If it helps, I had to move the .css files up to a different directory to get them to load (just one level down in uri segment math).  This is driving me nuts.

I put this in:

```
echo form_open('/profile/login');
$data = array(
          'name'        => 'email',
          'id'          => 'email',
          'value'       => '',
          'type'        => 'email',
        );
echo 'Email' . form_input($data);
echo 'Password' . form_password('password', '');
echo form_submit('usersubmit', 'Login');
```

and just get the same error as the original:

```
echo '<a href="/profile/">Click here</a> to login.</p>';
```

And this did the same thing (to test it):

```
$this->load->view('profile/index',$data);
```

The internal view function is getting called, and I can href to html pages outside of my environment...

I've done a text string search on the directory to find the "Error Loading Page" script, and can't find that either...

Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i see image of error

Comment: Got it.  Image is now attached.  Thanks

Comment: The error page itself won't tell you anything. You need to see what actual error occurred. Take a look at the server error log file if you have access to it. Or change the PHP or Codeigniter config to display useful error messages rather than a generic error (but avoid doing that on a live system)

Comment: Thanks @Spudley.  I posted the image because it isn't a typical error:warning box.  I've got error reporting on debug mode, and I don't get anything.  I'll look for a server error log.  The CI error log didn't pick up anything.  It was picking up a minor variable warning that was unrelated.  I fixed that and now get no errors.

Comment: So I found the source of the error -  jQuery Mobile 1.4.4, which makes us responsive (phonegap?).  I comment out that load and the error stops (formatting goes away too...).  The links try to load and I've got the error 403 on every view load.

Comment: can you try using a fresh copy of Codeigniter and test if the view loading works in it?

Comment: So it isn't CI at all - it is permissions.  I found the log file and and had about a million entries where XAMPP denied permission to load a file.  I searched online for how to allow permission, and found a site with lots of 'It worked!' comments, and added a 'username.conf' file per instructions.  Now, I can't start apache web server at all.  I uninstalled, rebooted, and reinstalled a fresh XAMPP instance, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, but...
pretty sure it is a security SSL issue - which is why the site works online, and not here.  I put the Apache logs on debug, which tells me a lot more, and there is a consistent issue with the SSL certs - apparently Apache isn't trusted, even on local machines, and I haven't figured out how to get around this.  Our original online site has SSL certs.  For the time being I'll do my edits on the live site - I've wasted almost 3 days hacking at this.  If anybody has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: For anybody who has this issue in the future:
1.  The SSL issue was 2 things - first, an out-of-date Apache Web Server Certificate.  If you need one for localhost, there are some really good links for solving that.  Second, SSL was required by .htaccess, in the root folder.  It's probably easier to just comment out those requirements until you deploy. 
2.  the Error Loading Page message is jQuery error-trapping.  If it doesn't find the object it seeks, it just posts the error message and cancels the event.  Still working on path issues - I'm getting a crash course in debugging.